# How to suppress legend entries in seaborn when plotting multiple times?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How to control the creation of legend entries for multiple calls to searborn's plotting functions? My problem can be illustrated with the following sample code:

```py
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
            palette=["m", "g"], data=tips)
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
              color="gray", alpha=0.3, data=tips, dodge=True, label=None)
plt.show()
```

This results in the below plot. How can I suppress the labels for the stripplot, which contain no additional information? I played with the argument `label`, without success.

[image]

Comment: @BigBen I was searching the web for a solution, but apparently kept the queries too generic. This is exactly what I need. Thanks! :)